# C# Bot Framework - Need second choiceset values to change upon selection of the first choiceset values

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I am working on an adaptive card in the Bot Framework. I need the values of the second choiceset to change upon selection of the first choiceset.

Comment: What channel are you using? This would only be possible in a channel that allows editing of conversation history. If your channel doesn't, you'd need a workaround like sending the second choiceset in a separate card on the next turn.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: I am currently using Microsoft Teams channel ,is it possible in that

Comment: Teams does allow editing of message history, yes. Can you post the Adaptive Card you're currently working with?

Comment: Are you still working on this?